# How can I construct a windowed aggregate query over an acceptable time window delta increment

Tags: sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions, date-arithmetic

I am recording user events into some `SQLite` tables.

Currently the tables are counting interactions over buckets of 1 minute which is updated on insertion.

The schema of the tables is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
                window DATETIME,
                counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
                value INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                file_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY(window,file_id)
            );

CREATE TABLE table2(
                window DATETIME,
                counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
                value INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                file_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY(window,file_id)
            );

CREATE TABLE files(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ON CONFLICT REPLACE DEFAULT 'NA', touched DATE DEFAULT (date('now')));
```

Insertion to the tables is performed like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO files(ROWID, name, touched)
    VALUES(
        (select ROWID FROM files WHERE name=IFNULL(?1,'NA') UNION SELECT max(ROWID) + 1 FROM files limit 1),
        IFNULL(?1,'NA'), 
        date()
    )

INSERT INTO table1(window,file_id,value)
        VALUES(
            datetime(strftime('%s', 'now') - (strftime('%s', 'now') % 60), 'unixepoch', 'localtime'),
            (SELECT rowid FROM files WHERE name=IFNULL(:fname,'NA')),
            :delta
        ) ON CONFLICT(window,file_id) DO
            UPDATE SET count = count + 1, value = value + :delta
```

Some example data would look like this:

```
select * from table1

window               file_id                 counter      value
-------------------  -------------------  -----------  ----------
2022-06-13 10:26:00  1                        29           3         
2022-06-13 10:27:00  2                        99           7
2022-06-13 10:30:00  3                        1            22
2022-06-13 10:31:00  4                        1            22
2022-06-13 10:34:00  1                        1            22
2022-06-13 10:39:00  1                        1            22
2022-06-13 10:40:00  1                        1            22
2022-06-13 10:53:00  1                        1            22
```

What I want to do is aggregate the "counter" and "value" columns based on active sessions. The session is considered active so long as the previous activity (row window) was within 10 minutes of the current activity (row windows separated by less than 10 minutes).

In this example, rows 1-7 belong to the same session since each activity (row window) is less than 10 minutes away from the previous activity. The last row defines a new session as it is 13 minutes after the previous activity ( 13 minutes = (10:53 - 10:40) is greater than 10 minutes).

This query should simultaneously aggregate from table2 (they are recorded at the same time but reflect different data)

My desired output should include data like this (per the rows 1-7 and row 8)

```
session 1:
started at: 2022-06-13 10:26:00
ended at:  2022-06-13 10:40:00
counter_sum: 22 + 99 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... +1 (the sum of count column)
value_sum: 3 + 7 + 22 + 22 .... + 22 (the sum of value column)

session 2:
start at: 2022-06-13 10:53:00
finished at: 2022-06-13 10:53:00 (since no data after this assume same time)
count_sum: 1
value_sum: 22
```

How would you construct this type of windowing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column that marks the active groups, like:

```
SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY window) grp
FROM (
  SELECT *, strftime('%s', window) - COALESCE(strftime('%s', LAG(window) OVER (ORDER BY window)), 0) > 600 flag
  FROM table1
);
```

and then you can aggregate based on that column like:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY window) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, strftime('%s', window) - COALESCE(strftime('%s', LAG(window) OVER (ORDER BY window)), 0) > 600 flag
    FROM table1
  )
)
SELECT grp,
       MIN(window) min_window,
       MAX(window) max_window,
       SUM(counter) sum_counter,
       SUM(value) sum_value
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=32127cc1f9e1feffe21c7ba50d6744cf).

Comment: looks really promising but seems to break if the file_id is different between rows. am I right?

Comment: @Avba I included file_id in the GROUP BY clause and all the window functions (I assume that this is what you want), so now it does not break.

Comment: doesn't seem correct (tried the same link you answered with, let me know if there is a new link). Here is an example:
INSERT INTO table1 (`window`, `file_id`, `counter`, `value`) VALUES
  ('2022-06-13 10:26:00', '1', '29', '3'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:27:00', '1', '99', '7'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:30:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:31:00', '3', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:34:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:39:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:40:00', '1', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 16:25:00', '4', '1', '22');

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=20da7d51f93317fd82bab74774d1365a

Comment: @Avba what is it that does not seem correct? Post your expected output.

Comment: all of these rows are together:
first result should include these entries
```
  ('2022-06-13 10:26:00', '1', '29', '3'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:27:00', '1', '99', '7'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:30:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:31:00', '3', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:34:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:39:00', '2', '1', '22'),
  ('2022-06-13 10:40:00', '1', '1', '22'),
```
and the second result (since more than 10 minutes from the previous line) 
should include this entry:
```  
('2022-06-13 16:25:00', '4', '1', '22');
```

Comment: Appologise for the formatting. I can edit my question if you like

Comment: @Avba what do you mean? Isn't file_id of no importance in your requirement? Rows with different file_ids should be considered as the same active group?